# Picking random elements from groupby using pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by, pandas-groupby

I have dataframe which looks like this:

```
    revisionId  itemId wikidataType
1    307190482      23           Q5
6    305019084      80           Q5
8    303692414     181           Q5
9    306600439     192           Q5
11   294597048     206           Q5
```

In complete dataframe, there are 100 such different values present in column wikidataType. Its a large dataframe, so I want to restrict it to 1000 records per wikidataType. Hence, I used following thing:

```
df = df[df.groupby('wikidataType')['wikidataType'].cumcount() < 1000]
```

This gives e like first 1000 records for each wikidataType. I want to choose these 1000 records randomly. So I tried using

```
df = df[random.sample(list(df.groupby('wikidataType')['wikidataType']), 1000)]
```

But gave an error as:

> TypeError: 'Series' objects are mutable, thus they cannot be hashed

I even tried

```
 df = df[df.groupby('wikidataType')['wikidataType'].cumcount().random() < 1000]
```

But that also didn't work. Anyone know how can I do this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A simpler method that I'd recommend, if you want the *first* 1000 elements, would be using `groupby` + `head`:

```
df = df.groupby('wikidataType').head(1000)
```

If you want 1000 *random* elements, call `sample`:

```
df = df.groupby('wikidataType', group_keys=False)\
                           .apply(lambda x: x.sample(1000))
```

You could choose to specify a fraction instead:

```
df = df.groupby('wikidataType', group_keys=False)\
                           .apply(lambda x: x.sample(frac=len(x) * .1))
```

Which gives you 10% of each element type. This would help if your population sizes vary, or if you have lesser than 1000 elements in any group.

---

A slight modification to this method, based on your comment, would be:

```
df = df.groupby('wikidataType', group_keys=False)\
               .apply(lambda x: x.sample(1000) if len(x) > 1000 else x)
```

Comment: I need 1000 records randomly. Not first 1000.

Comment: @NilakshiNaphade yeah, I was adding that in. See edit.

Comment: I probably will need that last fraction thing. But I want like min 1000 or all if size is less than 1000.

Comment: @NilakshiNaphade Made one more edit. Feel free to play around with it and adapt what suits your need the best.

Comment: I need little further help regarding same question. If I do not have 1000 records then I still need 1000 records but with replacement. E.g. If for wikidataType Q5 I have 900 records, then I want to repeat some random 100 records but from those 900 records. So finally I will have 900 distinct records, with 100 of them repeating. I used x.sample(1000, replace=True) but that gave me only 4 distinct records for type Q5, each of them was repeated many times, when I actually had 1000 distinct records for that type.

Answer (score 1):

In the new version of pandas you can simply do:

```
df = df.groupby('wikidataType').sample(1000)
```

Highly recommended because much simpler.

Comment: Does this take 1000 samples from each group?

Comment: Yes, it does, if there are not enough samples for each group, it will throw an error and you need use sampling with replacement: .sample(2, replace=True)